# Suddenly failed to use array type in the Azure Resource manager template parameter file

Tags: azure, parameters, azure-resource-manager

It seems ARM parameter file doesn't support the array type value.  The array type value in the parameter file was working before, but suddenly broken from all existing templates.

Have to put the  value of array type parameter into the template to make it working.

the output doesn't show the array type parameters from the parameter file properly

Template file:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "names": {
            "type": "array",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Indicate the name of app insight."
            },
            "defaultvalue": [
                "ain01",
                "ain02"
            ]
        }
        
    },
    "variables": {
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
            "name": "[parameters('names')[copyIndex()]]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
            "location": "canadacentral",
            "copy": {
                "count": "[length(parameters('names'))]",
                "name": "ainCopy"
            },
            "properties": {
                "applicationId": "[parameters('names')[copyIndex()]]"
            }
        }

    ],
    "outputs": {
        "names": {
          "type": "array",
          "value": "[parameters('names')]"
        }

    }
}
```

Parameter file:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "names": {
            "value": [
                "ain03",
                "ain04"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just share your ARM template, we can help without a message.

Comment: thanks for reply.  All the templates were working fine before yesterday. Suddently from yesterday, any array value in the parameter file will error out.  I have to move the array type value from the parameter file to the default value in the template. will upload the template.

Comment: @CharlesXu have shared a simple template as above. please investigate.  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

it seems the latest az.resources 2.5.0 module has some issue, can't read the array value from the parameter file properly.  I have rolled back to old module, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same problem and can confirm a rollback to az.resources 2.4.0 resolves the issue.

```
Uninstall-Module -Name Az.Resources
Install-Module -Name Az.Resources -RequiredVersion 2.4.0
```

It has also been reported here https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/12962